# get buffer which contains pdf from httpResponse and use it as an attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, parse-platform, sendgrid

I am trying a Get request from a remote url that contains a pdf and from its response get the buffer which contains the raw data and use it as an attachment to sendGrid but this doesn't seem to work because the pdf that is sent is empty.

Below find the code snippet that I use:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:"http://<MY_URL>/x.pdf",
    headers:{
        "X-Parse-Application-Id":"<MY_ID>",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "<MY_KEY>",
    } 
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    //email.addFileFromBuffer('x.pdf', httpResponse.buffer); 
    //-- Doesn't work raise and exception
    email.addFileFromBuffer(request.params.toName+'_report.pdf', new Buffer(httpResponse.text));
    sendgrid.send(email).then(function() {
        response.success("Email sent!");
    }, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong with sending email");
    });
}, function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong with pdf");
});
```

If anyone has a different idea on this.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT 1:**

When using :

```
email.addFileFromBuffer(request.params.toName+'_report.pdf', httpResponse.buffer);
```

Results in:

```
Ran cloud function sendEmail with:
Input: {"fileName":"x.pdf","toEmail":"xxx@gmail.com","toName":"XXX"}
Result: URIError: URI malformed
at encodeURIComponent (native)
at <anonymous>:325:38
at Parse.js:1:21050
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function.x.each.x.forEach (Parse.js:1:661)
at b._objectEach.b._each (Parse.js:1:21023)
at formEncode (<anonymous>:321:5)
at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest (<anonymous>:532:24)
at SendGrid.send (sendgrid.js:292:19)
at main.js:29:12
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` returns a `response` object that has both a raw byte and string representation. You don't need to create a new buffer, just use `response.buffer`.

Dig it:

```
email.addFileFromBuffer(request.params.toName+'_report.pdf', httpResponse.buffer);
```

Comment: When using email.addFileFromBuffer(request.params.toName+'_report.pdf', httpResponse.buffer);  Results in exception. Look at a more detailed trace on my edit 1.

Comment: what are the contents of request.params.toName when you get the error?

Comment: I have tried many different names even as constants. The simplest is xxx, so the output should be xxx_report.pdf.

Comment: Does the `httpRequest` call return a valid `httpResponse`? You're getting a malformed URI error and the only URI I see is the one for the file you are trying to get.

Comment: The url rendered from the browser so from a GET request is shown properly. The httpResponse logged is :
I2015-05-18T20:41:56.281Z]{"uuid":"9b54ee70-9e37-55b9-4b26-4c8a2d182100","status":200,"headers":{"Accept-Ranges":"bytes","Content-Length":"82545","Content-Type":"application/pdf","Date":"Mon, 18 May 2015 20:41:56 GMT","Etag":"\"01f477c048743af785638d76670539c9\"","Last-Modified":"Mon, 04 May 2015 21:03:03 GMT"},"text":"%PDF-1.4\n%\n5 0 obj\n<</Length 865/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream\nx]o0\u0014cWu\u0... (truncated)

Comment: Somehow the pdf in the buffer causes a URI malformed. Recently i found another open question with a relevant issue (https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse/issues/2)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you get buffer:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest('http://domain.net/assets/file.zip')
  .then(function(httpResponse) {
    httpResponse.buffer // <---- file contents here
  });
```

You cannot use buffer from binary file (it should work with plain/text) with this module. Take a look at https://github.com/m1gu3l/parse-sendgrid-mailer instead.